# How to remove a component of windows phone 8 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-8

i think it's a silly question...after I installed wp sdk 8 I found its size is more than 7 giga on c drive. So I want to remove some components to save the size, but when I select change from (Uninstall programs) it unistall all the sdk.
what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The only place where removing parts of the installation could help you get some space back is removing some of the emulator images. If you don't plan to develop for Windows Phone 7, you can remove these images and get few GB back for instance, but again, buy rather some larger SSD than speculate, what can be removed from Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Comment: OK Martin, if i don't want to develop for WP 7, which images I should remove and how to do that?

Comment: I think it's in the C:\All Users\Microsoft\XDE folder.